# Putting text at the side of a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I've just completed a tikz diagram. I need the text

> In the following diagram, what can you say about $\angle F$, $\angle
>   B$ and$\angle E$?

to go to the right of the diagram to save space on the paper.

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.27,0.27,0.27}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49,0.49,1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-4.3,-5.44) rectangle (18.7,6.3);
\draw(0,0) circle (4.01cm);
\draw (-4.01,0)-- (0,0);
\draw (0,0)-- (4.01,0);
\draw (-0.28,4)-- (-4.01,0);
\draw (-0.28,4)-- (4.01,0);
\draw (-4.01,0)-- (1.62,3.67);
\draw (1.62,3.67)-- (4.01,0);
\draw (-2.27,3.3)-- (-4.01,0);
\draw (-2.27,3.3)-- (4.01,0);
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (0.14,0.28) node {$A$};
\fill [color=black] (-0.28,4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.12,4.28) node {$B$};
\fill [color=black] (-4.01,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-3.84,0.28) node {$C$};
\fill [color=black] (4.01,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.16,0.28) node {$D$};
\fill [color=black] (1.62,3.67) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.78,3.94) node {$E$};
\fill [color=black] (-2.27,3.3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-2.14,3.58) node {$F$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center} 
In the following diagram, what can you say about $\angle F$, $\angle B$ and$\angle E$? 
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: :-D JLDiaz thanks! wow so many smart people tonight

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are two approaches:

## 1. To include the text as part of the figure

You have to simply add a node inside the `tikzpicture`. It will be useful to limit the width of the text, and to play with anchors to position it at the required place. eg:

```
\node[text width=6cm, anchor=west, right] at (5,0)
    {In this diagram, what can you say about $\angle F$, $\angle B$ and $\angle E$?};
```

[image: in picture]

## 2. To put the text out of the `tikzpicture` environment.

For this solution you have to keep in mind that, for TeX, your complete figure is like a *HUGE* character, part of a sentence, so you can put your text right after that "character" and TeX will make a paragraph with it

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Your code
\end{tikzpicture}
In this diagram, what can you say about $\angle F$, $\angle B$ and$\angle E$?
```

However if you try this with your code, you'll get the following strange result:

[image: Strange]

This is because you included this line in your figure:

```
\clip(-4.3,-5.44) rectangle (18.7,6.3);
```

which causes the figure to have a width of 18.7 cm, and height of 6.3cm. This line is unnecessary and can be safely removed, producing:

[image: Paragraph]

You can see that the figure is used as a big char, part of a "normal" paragraph. However the result is ugly, because the text warps and continues below the figure.

This can be avoided putting the text inside a `\parbox` which will produce a box of a fixed width containing the text. TeX will treat this whole box as another "big char", and put it next to the figure:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Your code
\end{tikzpicture}
\parbox[b]{4cm}{
   In this diagram, what can you say about $\angle F$, $\angle B$ and$\angle E$?
}
```

Option `[b]` is to specify where is the "baseline" of this box. Baselines are aligned in the same horizontal line when composing a paragraph. The tikz picture has its baseline at its bottom, so if we give `[b]` option to the parbox, making it baseline also at the bottom, both will be aligned:

[image: Bottom aligned]

If you omit `[b]` in the parbox, the resulting parbox will have its baseline at its center. This will align the center of the parbox with the bottom of the figure, and this is ugly. To get the same output than in case 1 (text embedded in tikz picture), we need to change the baseline of the figure, and put it at its center. Fortunately `tikz` has a simple option for this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0, ...remaining options...]
% Your code
\end{tikzpicture}
\hskip{1cm}\parbox{4cm}{
   In this diagram, what can you say about $\angle F$, $\angle B$ and$\angle E$?
}
```

Produces:

[image: Aligned at center]

For completeness I'll include also the case of top-alignment, which is a bit trickier than others. You could think that, to get top alignment, it would be enough to put the `baseline` of the tikz figure at its top, and use `[t]` option for the parbox. However this does not work as expected.

First, the tikz picture. Which value should I write for `baseline` option? It can accept a number, which is a measure from the bottom border, or the coordinates of a node. In this case, I know (reading the code) that the circle has a radius around `4` units, so I could use `baseline=4cm`, but this is not taking into account the space needed for the label *B* on top, and it is not a general solution. The general solution is to give the option `baseline=(current bounding box.north)`.

Second, the `[t]` option for `parbox` does not put the baseline "at the top of that box", but instead "at the basline of the top line of that box". So, the baseline of the first line of text will be aligned with the top border of the figure, as the following figure shows (I added a border to the figure to make more evident the issue):

[image: Bad alignment]

The solution is to include an "empty" line as the first line of the `parbox`. It can be achieved with `\vskip0pt`. This will produce a line which has no height or depth, but since it is the first line of the parbox, it will be used as baseline, and it is exactly at the top of that box. This is the code:

```
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north), ...]
% Your code
\end{tikzpicture}}
\parbox[t]{4cm}{\vskip0pt
   In this diagram, what can you say about $\angle F$, $\angle B$ and$\angle E$?
}
```

[image: Correct alignment]

Comment: For the sake of completeness, it would be interesting to see the code to align the figure and the parbox at its top. tks

Comment: @LaRaison Ok, I've updated the answer

Comment: Very nice trick!

Comment: Thank you! It works even to put enumerate side by side with the figure!

Answer (score 7):

You can use two `minipage` environment. If you need to clip your picture, you can use `trim left` and `trim right` see the pgfmanual for explanations.

You don't need to load `pgf` but only `tikz` and you can reduce your code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,scale=.6,font=\scriptsize]  

    \draw (0,0) circle (4.01cm) node [above]{$A$};
    \draw (-4.01,0) node[left] {$C$}
          -- (0,0)
          -- (4.01,0) node [right]{$D$} 
          -- (-0.28,4)node[above] {$B$} 
          -- (-4.01,0) 
          -- (1.62,3.67)node[above] {$E$}
          -- (4.01,0) 
          -- (-2.27,3.3) node[above] {$F$} -- cycle;
        \fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt)
                          (-0.28,4) circle (1.5pt)
                          (-4.01,0) circle (1.5pt)
                          (4.01,0) circle (1.5pt)
                          (1.62,3.67) circle (1.5pt) 
                          (-2.27,3.3) circle (1.5pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    In the following diagram, what can you say about $\angle F$, $\angle B$ and$\angle E$? 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now if you want to put the text and the figure at its top

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,scale=.6,font=\scriptsize]  

    \draw (0,0) circle (4.01cm) node [above]{$A$};
    \draw (-4.01,0) node[left] {$C$}
          -- (0,0)
          -- (4.01,0) node [right]{$D$} 
          -- (-0.28,4)node[above] {$B$} 
          -- (-4.01,0) 
          -- (1.62,3.67)node[above] {$E$}
          -- (4.01,0) 
          -- (-2.27,3.3) node[above] {$F$} -- cycle;
        \fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt)
                          (-0.28,4) circle (1.5pt)
                          (-4.01,0) circle (1.5pt)
                          (4.01,0) circle (1.5pt)
                          (1.62,3.67) circle (1.5pt) 
                          (-2.27,3.3) circle (1.5pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    In the following diagram, what can you say about $\angle F$, $\angle B$ and$\angle E$? 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Package [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) also offers another way of distributing graphics/tabulars and text side by side. `\tcbsidebyside` box accepts two parameters, left and right contents to be distributed side by side, and `sidebyside adapt` option allows to declare which part will define space distribution. `sidebyside align` defines vertical alignment of both parts.

With `TikZ` code taken from Alain's answer, the result could be:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\tcbsidebyside[sidebyside adapt=left, blanker, sidebyside gap=1cm, 
               sidebyside align=top seam]{%  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,scale=.6,font=\scriptsize]  
        \draw (0,0) circle (4.01cm) node [above]{$A$};
        \draw (-4.01,0) node[left] {$C$}
          -- (0,0)
          -- (4.01,0) node [right]{$D$} 
          -- (-0.28,4)node[above] {$B$} 
          -- (-4.01,0) 
          -- (1.62,3.67)node[above] {$E$}
          -- (4.01,0) 
          -- (-2.27,3.3) node[above] {$F$} -- cycle;
        \fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt)
                          (-0.28,4) circle (1.5pt)
                          (-4.01,0) circle (1.5pt)
                          (4.01,0) circle (1.5pt)
                          (1.62,3.67) circle (1.5pt) 
                          (-2.27,3.3) circle (1.5pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}{In the following diagram, what can you say about $\angle F$, $\angle B$ and$\angle E$?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And without `blanker` option, all `tcolorbox` bells and whistles can be applied:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\tcbsidebyside[title=A \texttt{\textbackslash{}tcbsidebyside} example,
sidebyside adapt=left, 
sidebyside gap=1cm, 
bicolor, colback=green!10, colbacklower=yellow!10, drop lifted shadow, fonttitle=\bfseries]{%  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,scale=.6,font=\scriptsize]  

    \draw (0,0) circle (4.01cm) node [above]{$A$};
    \draw (-4.01,0) node[left] {$C$}
          -- (0,0)
          -- (4.01,0) node [right]{$D$} 
          -- (-0.28,4)node[above] {$B$} 
          -- (-4.01,0) 
          -- (1.62,3.67)node[above] {$E$}
          -- (4.01,0) 
          -- (-2.27,3.3) node[above] {$F$} -- cycle;
        \fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt)
                          (-0.28,4) circle (1.5pt)
                          (-4.01,0) circle (1.5pt)
                          (4.01,0) circle (1.5pt)
                          (1.62,3.67) circle (1.5pt) 
                          (-2.27,3.3) circle (1.5pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}{In the following diagram, what can you say about $\angle F$, $\angle B$ and$\angle E$?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\tcbsidebyside` is a new feature of `tcolorbox` (released in november 2015). In my opinion it is the best way to put text at the side of a tikzpicture right now.