# How can I place an image in a marginpar and make it position itself according to the top of the image

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, marginpar

As demonstrated by the following MWE, I've placed a simple image in the margin of a document. What appears to happen is the caption text is vertically aligned with the line that I type the `\marginpar` command on, and the image sits above it. Is there any way I can make the top of the image be in line with the line of text in the body where I include the `\marginpar` command? I need to be able to do this to accurately have an idea where images are going to appear when I typeset a textbook I'm making.

Thanks

Please don't mind the incredibly not straight line I tried to draw to emphasize my point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{test}
  This is a test.\marginpar{
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{resources/Georg_Cantor2.jpg}
    \captionof{figure}{Georg Cantor (1845-1918) was a German mathematician, best known as the inventor of set theory, which has become a fundamental theory in mathematics.}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just check : [Putting text at the side of a tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99224/putting-text-at-the-side-of-a-tikzpicture/99231#99231). Just add :\vskip0pt like this... \marginpar{ \vskip0pt  ...

Answer (score 2):

```
\marginpar{\vskip0pt\includegraphics...}
```

This worked very well. Probably  not the optimal solution, but it does the job for the time being. Thanks very much La Raison.