# Insert text below a figure with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, article

I am making a newsletter, but I am not expert at all, especially with the new Latex features like 'tikz'. I want a big picture in the first page (the cover), with some written lines at the bottom of the page, and at the center, so that copyrights and years etc. can be specified.

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=1cm, bmargin=0.2cm, tmargin=1cm, rmargin=1cm, centering, includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} %pagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\definecolor{boxgray}{RGB}{139,137,137}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor = north west, inner sep=0] (image) at (current page.north west) 
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.9\paperheight]{whatever.eps}};

    \node[align = center, anchor = below] at (current page.south) {\textcopyright\, 2014 ... individual authors. All rights reserved.\\ Other bla bla words};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I thought it was easy, but I can not manage to have a nice layout, unless I specify things and position by numbers, in a very artificial way. I don't know very well how 'nodes' work. I read a lot on this SE as well, especially [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99224/putting-text-at-the-side-of-a-tikzpicture), but still seems I can't follow all the available options. A clear example would be very welcome.

As a beside, I [read from here](http://desktoppub.about.com/cs/pagelayout/ht/perfect_margins.htm) some general rules about the blank margins: if anyone knows any useful advice on that it would be very good, since the guide says that it is better to avoid equally spaced margins on all sides, but it does not give any example numbers.

Comment: Unless you are already a LaTeX expert (and it seems that you are not), making a newsletter with a complex free-form layout is perhaps better done with a page layout program.

Comment: @bubba, thanks for the suggestion, but what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I was referring to software like Adobe InDesign or QuarkXPress. These are the tools that are typically used for complex visually-oriented page layout.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9561/30481

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A rectangular node has no anchor called below. Either use `anchor=south` for your text node

```
\node[align = center, anchor=south] at (current page.south) {\textcopyright\, 2014 ... individual authors. All rights reserved.\\ Other bla bla words};
```

or use

```
\node[align = center, above] at (current page.south) {\textcopyright\, 2014 ... individual authors. All rights reserved.\\ Other bla bla words};
```

The option `above` changes the node anchor to `south`. In both cases the `south` anchor of your text node will be inserted at the `(current page.south)`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=1cm, bmargin=0.2cm, tmargin=1cm, rmargin=1cm, centering, includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads also graphicx and xcolor

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mwe}% example-image

\definecolor{boxgray}{RGB}{139,137,137}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor = north west, inner sep=0] (image) at (current page.north west) 
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.9\paperheight]{example-image}};

    \node[align = center, above] at (current page.south) {\textcopyright\, 2014 ... individual authors. All rights reserved.\\ Other bla bla words};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `below = of image` from the `positioning` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=1cm, bmargin=0.2cm, tmargin=1cm, rmargin=1cm, centering, includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} %pagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning} % <----
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\definecolor{boxgray}{RGB}{139,137,137}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor = north west, inner sep=0] (image) at (current page.north west) 
        {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.9\paperheight]{frog.jpg}};

    \node[align = center, below = of image] % <---- 
        {\textcopyright\, 2014 ... individual authors. All rights reserved.\\ Other bla bla words};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]