# Tikz, text outside plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz, annotations

[image]I just included matlab figures using matlab2tikz.
I have annotations in my figures. These annotations are outside the plot area to prevent overlap with the data. But now I also want the annotations outside the plot in my latex file. If possible i want to implement it into the tikz file(not in the latex file).

I tried the following using `minipage

> `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99224/putting-text-at-the-side-of-a-tikzpicture`
>
> `setting clip=false` (Didn't do anything)

Minipage worked but when i resized my plot in latex the annotations didn't scale and are now halve inside the plot.

```
using node[text width=6cm, anchor=west, right] at (5,0)
    {In this diagram, what can you say about $\angle F$, $\angle B$ and $\angle E$?};
```

from the same link (Didn't work)

I'm not very experienced with Tikz. I just tried some different methods, but none seems to work.

here is the tikz file:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=0.951\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=30,
xmax=330,
xlabel={$\text{T}_{\text{surr}}\text{ (K)}$},
ymin=0,
ymax=120,
ylabel={$\text{Q}_{\text{Cooling}}\text{ (W)}$},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={Cooling power for surrounding temperatures},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
30  6.97463548006898\\
60  7.00516177264937\\
90  7.36872538108224\\
120 8.92825821383692\\
150 12.7097699247381\\
180 19.3898073983116\\
210 29.107506124354\\
240 42.0222333872511\\
270 58.3725938451868\\
300 78.4696582472676\\
330 102.691450312509\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=1.227\figurewidth,
height=1.227\figureheight,
at={(-0.16\figurewidth,-0.135\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
hide axis,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
**\node[below right, align=left, text=black, draw=black]
at (rel axis cs:0.75,0.15) {G10 \\$\text{ }\epsilon\text{ = 1 }$\\ F = 1 \\$\text{ T}_{\text{start}}\text{ = 330 }$\\$\text{ T}_{\text{end}}\text{ = 30 }$\\$\text{ dT}_{\text{max}}\text{ = 1 }$\\ N = 100};**
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sorry, where is tikz file?

Comment: I added the tikzfile code

Comment: There's still no MWE (starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works if you add `clip=false` to the second `axis` environment, containing the `node` with the annotation. Having done that you can just move it to the position of your choice, by changing the coordinates for the `\node`.

That said, the second `axis` environment is not really necessary here, you might as well add it inside the first `axis` environment, or right outside it, placing it relative to the axis.

In the code below both options are demonstrated. Note that I've added `name=MyAxis` to the `axis` options, and the node is placed at `MyAxis.north east`. I don't know what `G10` is, but it seemed like it was a heading of sorts, hence the bold text. Of course, remove that `\textbf` if you don't want it. I also set the list of values using `aligned`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}
\newlength{\figurewidth}
\setlength{\figurewidth}{10cm}
\newlength{\figureheight}
\setlength{\figureheight}{5cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
name=MyAxis,
width=0.951\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=30,
xmax=330,
xlabel={${T}_{\text{surr}}\text{ (K)}$},
ymin=0,
ymax=120,
ylabel={$\text{Q}_{\text{Cooling}}\text{ (W)}$},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={Cooling power for surrounding temperatures},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
%clip=false %uncomment this if you want the annotation outside the axis
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
30  6.97463548006898\\
60  7.00516177264937\\
90  7.36872538108224\\
120 8.92825821383692\\
150 12.7097699247381\\
180 19.3898073983116\\
210 29.107506124354\\
240 42.0222333872511\\
270 58.3725938451868\\
300 78.4696582472676\\
330 102.691450312509\\
};

\node[below right, align=center, text=black]
at (rel axis cs:0.1,0.9) {\textbf{G10} \\
$\begin{aligned} 
\epsilon &= 1\\
 F &= 1 \\
T_{\text{start}} &= 330 \\
T_{\text{end}} &= 30\\
\mathrm{d}T_{\text{max}}&= 1\\
 N &= 100
\end{aligned}$};

\end{axis}

\node[below right, align=center, text=black]
at (MyAxis.north east) {%
\textbf{G10} \\
$\begin{aligned} 
\epsilon &= 1\\
 F &= 1 \\
T_{\text{start}} &= 330 \\
T_{\text{end}} &= 30\\
\mathrm{d}T_{\text{max}}&= 1\\
 N &= 100
\end{aligned}$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Torbjorn, Thanks a lot for explaining and also showing that i need only 1 axis. The second axes is probably because i added the annotations inside matlab. Only one question remains. I get a error message (see image in post) when i dont remove everything above \begin{tikzpicture} and below \end{tikzpicture}. Is the rest to save at as a tex. file and externalise the image to prevent exceeding the Tex capacity? This happens if i add a different picture. But I have'n't figure out how to load .tex file if i save it like that, because \begin{figure}[htb]
 \input{mysphere.tex} 
\end{figure}

Comment: @fahrenheiz I don't fully understand. To use it as `\begin{figure}\input{file.tex}\end{figure}`, `file.tex` cannot contain a `\documentclass`, the preamble and `document` environment, it should *only* contain the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: The script is an external tikz or tex file. The begin figure,input is to include into my main tex file which is a report with the different graphs. But this doesn't seem to work for most images because the Tex capapacity is exceeded.

Comment: I get now that the \documentclass is only for the main document, but looking around this capacity error i see that most people don't use matlab2tikz but only use the data from matlab and do the plotting in a different way.

Comment: @fahrenheiz That can happen with large datafiles, but is unrelated to the error you show in the image. Externalisation doesn't help? Can you compile with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`?

Comment: @fahrenheiz Either way, the capacity problem is completely unrelated to the question I answered, so it would be better if you asked a new question, assuming you cannot find an existing one with a useful solution.

Comment: Yea sorry, you answered my question the error above is resolved. Really thank you  for that. It is just that I still have no way of making  neat matlab figures into latex.

Comment: @fahrenheiz I guess `matlab2tikz` does an OK job in a lot of cases. You could of course just export the data from Matlab as `.csv` files and learn to use `pgfplots` (see the manual for all the details, and https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-1/tb97wright-pgfplots.pdf for a quick intro). That wont help with the capacity problem of course, but it does give you more flexibility if you do things on your own. As mentioned, compiling with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` can help some, as can using the `external` library, or downsampling the data.