# tcolorbox and tikz: two pictures in two columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

Basically I want two tikzpictures of the *same size* aligned in two columns. To realise this I use the `tcolorbox` package with its `\tcbsidebyside{}`-command. The problem is that the picture in the second column has the wrong size and I have no idea why.

> How can I get two tikzpictures of the same size with a small gap
>   between them with the help of the `\tscsidebyside`-command?

In the following pictures the green boxes show what I'm looking for...

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\tcbsidebyside[
    sidebyside adapt=left,
    blanker,
    sidebyside gap=0.5\baselineskip,
    sidebyside align=top seam
]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\linewidth/20cm]
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-3.45) grid (4.95,3.45);
        \draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
        \draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\tcbsidebyside[
    sidebyside adapt=left,
    blanker,
    sidebyside gap=0.5\baselineskip,
    sidebyside align=top seam
]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\linewidth/20cm]
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-3.45) grid (4.95,3.45);
        \draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
        \draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\linewidth/20cm]
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-3.45) grid (4.95,3.45);
        \draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
        \draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The \linewidth changes inside tcbsidebyside. And due to the `sidebyside adapt=left` the sides are not handled in the same way. Store the linewidth outside e.g. with `\newlength\mylinewidth \mylinewidth=\linewidth` and then use \mylinewidth for the scale factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\tcbsidebyside changes internally \linewidth, and as you are using the `sidebyside adapt=left`, both sides are not affected in the same way. It is better to use an independant length for the scaling.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newlength\mylinewidth
\AtBeginDocument{\mylinewidth=\linewidth\relax}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\tcbsidebyside[
    sidebyside adapt=left,
    blanker,
    sidebyside gap=0.5\baselineskip,
    sidebyside align=top seam
]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\mylinewidth/20cm]
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-3.45) grid (4.95,3.45);
        \draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
        \draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.


\tcbsidebyside[
    sidebyside adapt=left,
    blanker,
    sidebyside gap=0.5\baselineskip,
    sidebyside align=top seam
]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\mylinewidth/20cm]
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-3.45) grid (4.95,3.45);
        \draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
        \draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\mylinewidth/20cm]
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-3.45) grid (4.95,3.45);
        \draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
        \draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion it is better to use `(\mylinewidth-0.5\baselineskip)/20cm` instead of `\mylinewidth/20cm` as a scale factor. Am I right? PS: `0.5\baselineskip` is the gap between both pictures in this case.

Comment: Sounds ok (but I don't know where the 20cm comes from). I didn't really check, what tcolorbox is doing with \linewidth in parts.

Comment: The width of my tikzpicture is 10cm (to be exact: 9.90cm). To scale it relativly to the linewidth someone can use e.g. `scale=\linewidth/10cm` (source: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32627/101831)). I use 20cm so that I can align two pictures next to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Although this answer does not uses `\tscsidebyside` as the OP explicitly requested, I'm leaving it as a reference which may be useful to other readers.

**Original Answer**

You don't need to use tcolorbox for the single purpose of putting things side-by-side. You can use `\parbox` or other standard latex environments to put blocks of text side-by-side, and you don't require any special environment to put tikzpictures side by side, but only to adjust if required the baseline of the figure.

For more info, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123895/positioning-tikz-pictures/123900#123900), or [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99224/putting-text-at-the-side-of-a-tikzpicture/99231#99231) and also the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\textwidth/20cm, baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-3.45) grid (4.95,3.45);
        \draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
        \draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{1mm}
\parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{\vskip0pt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.


    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\linewidth/20cm]
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-3.45) grid (4.95,3.45);
        \draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
        \draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
    \end{tikzpicture}\hspace{1mm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\linewidth/20cm]
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-3.45) grid (4.95,3.45);
        \draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
        \draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=2.25, y radius=3.4];
    \end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]